# Mapstruct + lombok unable to run in command line but working in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, java-8, lombok, mapper

When i try to do mvn clean install i am getting below error:

/mapper/Test.java:[62,23] Unknown property "testDTO.a" in result type dto.testDTO. Did you mean "null"?

When I try to run from intelliJ code is working.

Root cause: When i try to run in intellij,lombok will run first and generate getter and setter but when i run in command prompt i get above error. I saw several blogs but i could not resolve it.I also saw some stack overflow answers but i could not resolve it.

How to solve it. Thanks in advance.

MapperInterface:

```
@Mapping(source = "testDTO",
         target = "testDTO.a")
```

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What Lombok and MapStruct versions do you use?

Comment: Lombok : 1.18.0
MapStruct : 3.5 (Tried with different versions also)

Comment: You cannot have MapStruct v. 3.5, latest MapStruct version is 1.3.1. Btw. in my projects I always have in dependencies mapstruct, mapstruct-processor & lombok and I don't have to use annotationProcessorPaths like you did and everything works just fine.

Comment: @jirka.pinkas ..Sorry thats my bad

       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.0</org.projectlombok.version>